# Prove that the union of these measurable sets is less than $\epsilon$ for some large $N$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $E_k \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable for each $k = 1,2,\dots$ and $$m(E_k) < \frac{1}{2^k}$$ Prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that $$m(\bigcup_{k = N}^{\infty} E_k) < \epsilon$$

This one I've had a bit of trouble figuring out how to start. Nothing seems to be jumping out to me directly. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{k}}=\frac1{2^{N-1}}$$

Comment: Hint:


See hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$m\left(\bigcup_{k=N}^\infty E_k\right)\leq \sum_{k=N}^\infty m(E_k)$$

Comment: So then $\sum_{k = N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^{N-1}} < \epsilon$. Is that it?

Comment: @DominicBlanco Yes it is.

Comment: Great! I can't accept it for a few minutes, but that does make sense. I just did not think about making the union into a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{k}}=\frac1{2^{N-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The other two comments mention proofs specific to this case, but you can actually prove a much, much more general statement. If $A_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $m(A_n) < a_n$ where $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\left|\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n\right| < \infty$, then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find an $N$ so that $m\left(\bigcup_{n = N}^{\infty}A_n\right) < \varepsilon$. To prove this, we need a lemma that if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n < \infty$ then there is an $N$ so that $\sum_{n = N}^{\infty}a_n < \varepsilon$. This follows since the sequence of partial sums converges, so it is cauchy; in particular, we can find an $N$ so that if $m \geq N$, then $\sum_{n = N}^{m}a_n < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, so then $\sum_{n = N}^{\infty} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, and choose $N$ so that $\sum_{n = N}^{\infty}a_n < \varepsilon$. Then, we can use subadditivity; $m\left(\bigcup_{n \geq N}A_n\right) \leq \sum_{n = N}^{\infty}m(A_n) = \sum_{n = N}^{\infty}a_n < \varepsilon$ as desired. Applying this result to this case gives the proof you want (since $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2^{-n} = 1 < \infty$), but also gives you a more general result which is often helpful.